# How to split nested array into "rows" with limited size

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an array of arrays of different sizes. The goal is to generate "rows" where each row can contain a max of 12 elements.
For example:

Input data can be something like this:
`const groups = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

```
groups[0].length + groups[1].length = 10 -> row0
groups[2].length = 12 -> row1
groups[3].length + groups[4].length = 10 -> row3
groups[5].length = 3 -> row4
```

Output for such array should be:

```
[[[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5,6]], [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]], [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3]], [[1,2,3]]]
```

I was thinking of a recursive function for this but couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do this.

The code first checks if the current last element (last "row") has more than 12 numbers in it if you add the next group:

```
(acc[acc.length - 1].flat().length + cv.length) <= 12
```

if it will be less than 12, the elements will get pushed into the "row":

```
acc[acc.length - 1].push(cv)
```

and if not, a new "row" will be added to the outer array:

```
acc.push([cv])
```

```js
const groups = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3]];

const rows = groups.reduce((acc, cv) => {
  (acc[acc.length - 1].flat().length + cv.length) <= 12 ?
      acc[acc.length - 1].push(cv) :
      acc.push([cv])
  return acc
}, [[]]);


console.log(JSON.stringify(rows))
```

Comment: Thank you for a prompt solution! Worked like a charm. I will also customize it so we can pass "row" size to function!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to solve it recursively:

```js
const regroup = (max, [g, ...gs], filled = [], curr = [], cc = 0) =>
  g == undefined
    ? filled .concat ([curr])
  : g .length + cc <= max
    ? regroup (max, gs, filled, curr .concat ([g]), cc + g.length)
  : regroup (max, gs, filled .concat ([curr]), [g], g .length)

const groups = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

console .log (regroup (12, groups))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We pass the maximum size and the list of items, and then we default three parameters:

- `filled` will track the output rows we've filled; it starts with an empty array
- `curr` stores the row we're working on; it also starts with an empty array
- `cc` stores the count of all elements in the current row; it starts with zero

On each recursive call, we have one of three possibilities:

- There are no more arrays to process, and we return all the filled rows with the current row appended.
- The next array is small enough to fit in the current row, and we update the current to include it, and the current count to accommodate it.
- The next array is too large, and we add the existing current row to the filled ones, and start a new current row with this array, setting the count appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, @Scott! Very elegant and sophisticated solution! Having '12' as a parameter is a good idea! Feel like now it's a good interview question. Cheers!